# System.Environment.OSVersion .NET Core 5.0 Framework replacement?

Tags: c#, .net-core

`System.Environment.OSVersion` doesn't seem to be a part of .net core 5.0 (dnxcore50).

I am trying to determine which OS a user is on so when they save a file to the filesystem I know rather to use '/' or '\'

What should I use instead?

Comment: Apparently, this feature has been [deliberately left out](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1017) to prevent developers from using version numbers to check for feature availability. What is the underlying problem that you want to solve?

Comment: There was discussion about this issue on github:  https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1017. At this moment this functionality is not available

Comment: I am trying to determine which OS a user is on so when they save a file to the filesystem i know rather to use '/' or '\'

Comment: You could use `Path.Combine` (unless it's also left out).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do the detection yourself. Use [System.IO.Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx).[DirectorySeparatorChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, if you always use Path to manipulate paths then you should get formatting that you need. This also works with URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it back:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace System
{


    // [ComVisible(true)]
    // [Serializable]
    public enum PlatformID
    {
        Win32S = 0,
        Win32Windows = 1,
        Win32NT = 2,
        WinCE = 3,
        Unix = 4,
        // Since NET 3.5 SP1 or silverlight
        Xbox = 5,
        MacOSX = 6,
    }


    public class OperatingSystem
    {
        private Architecture m_arch;
        private bool m_isARM;
        private bool m_isX86;
        private bool m_isLinux;
        private bool m_isOSX;
        private bool m_isWindows;
        private PlatformID m_platform;

        public OperatingSystem()
        {
            m_arch = RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture;
            m_isARM = (m_arch == Architecture.Arm || m_arch == Architecture.Arm64);
            m_isX86 = (m_arch == Architecture.X86 || m_arch == Architecture.X64);

            m_isLinux = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux);
            m_isOSX = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX);
            m_isWindows = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows);

            if (m_isLinux || m_isOSX)
                m_platform = PlatformID.Unix;
            else if (m_isWindows)
            {
                m_platform = PlatformID.Win32NT;
            }
            else
                throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException("Operating system not supported.");
        }

        public PlatformID Platform
        {
            get
            {
                return m_platform;
            }
        }
    }



    public class OldEnvironment
    {

        private static OperatingSystem m_OS;

        static OldEnvironment()
        {
            m_OS = new OperatingSystem();
        }

        public static OperatingSystem OSVersion
        {
            get
            {
                return m_OS;
            }
        }

    }


}
```